# One single colored letter inside \spacedallcaps

Tags: spacing, color

I want to change the color of a single letter inside a custom `\spacedallcaps` command. This command makes the specified text uppercase and changes the letter spacing.

When I introduce a `\textcolor{color}{letter}` it will simply not work.

Also, taking the letter out of the `\spacedallcaps` piece of text works only if the specified letter is at the end or at the beginning. But how can I manage this when the letter is in the middle of a word?

I tried the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase
\usepackage{soul} % for letterspacing
\sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.25em}{0.8em}{0.6em} % : {space between letters}{space between words}{0.6em}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}} % all caps with better spacing

\begin{document}
\spacedallcaps{One single colored letter}\\

\spacedallcaps{One single col}\hspace{0.25em}\textcolor{red}{O}\spacedallcaps{red letter}\\

\spacedallcaps{One single col}\hspace{0.25em}\textcolor{red}{O}\hspace{0.25em}\spacedallcaps{red letter}
\end{document}
```

But the result is far from being good :

[image: result]

One can always play with the `\hspace` function but it is extremely tedious as it requires endless trials.

How can one achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `xcolor` instead of `color` and issue

```
\colorlet{RED}{red}
```

because `\MakeTextUppercase` also "uppercases" `red` inside `\textcolor`.

At this point (notice `\textcolor` inside braces)

```
\spacedallcaps{One single col{\textcolor{red}{O}}red letter}
```

would suffice.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase
\usepackage{soul} % for letterspacing
\sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.25em}{0.8em}{0.6em} % : {space between letters}{space between words}{0.6em}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}} % all caps with better spacing

\colorlet{RED}{red}

\begin{document}
\spacedallcaps{One single col{\textcolor{red}{O}}red letter}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

I would like to add a suggestion from [Christopher](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73570) for adjusting the spacing between letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\textsc{#1}}} % all caps with better spacing

\colorlet{RED}{red}

\begin{document}

\spacedallcaps{\lsstyle One single col\textcolor{red}{O}red letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat! This works perfectly

Comment: Perhaps you should explain, why `RED` is necessary ;-) (+1 anyway)

Comment: @karlkoeller Just a small reminder : microtype will not work if one compiles with XeLaTeX or such.

Comment: @jrojasqu I know, but I wanted to add Christopher's solution, who deleted his answer, which was intended as a comment on my answer. Letter spacing is supported only by pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but it's not a bad suggestion. Anyway I'm trying to undelete his answer, so I will remove that part from mine. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can register commands for `soul`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcase} % for \MakeTextUppercase
\usepackage{soul} % for letterspacing
\sodef\allcapsspacing{\upshape}{0.25em}{0.8em}{0.6em} % : {space between letters}{space between words}{0.6em}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{%
  \MakeTextUppercase{\allcapsspacing{#1}}%
} % all caps with better spacing

\DeclareRobustCommand{\makered}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\soulregister{\makered}{1}

\begin{document}
\spacedallcaps{One single col{\makered{o}}red letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to see if this would work with my `\spaceout` macro, not using `soul`.

EDITED to provide for separate inter-word spacing.

Provides definitions `\theLetterSpace` and `\theWordSpace` as default inter-letter and  inter-word spacing (Note that `\theWordSpace` is **in addition to** the natural `\` space that accompanies word breaks).  By default, I set `\theWordSpace` to 1.5 x the local letter-spacing, dynamically readjusted as `\theLetterSpace` changes.  The local value of the letter spacing can also be changed with an optional argument to `\spaceout`, as shown in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\parskip 1ex
\colorlet{RED}{red}
\begin{document}
test \uppercase{\spaceout[5pt]{one single col{\textcolor{red}{o}}red letter}} with 5pt added spacing

test \uppercase{\spaceout[3pt]{one single col{\textcolor{red}{o}}red letter}} with  3pt added spacing

test \uppercase{\spaceout[1pt]{one single col{\textcolor{red}{o}}red letter}} with  1pt added spacing

\def\theWordSpace{5\LocalLetterSpace}Change the inter-word spacing to 5 x local letter spacing.

test \uppercase{\spaceout[1pt]{one single col{\textcolor{red}{o}}red letter}} with  1pt added spacing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am interested in your macro : how do you manage the word spacing? Can it be incremented or is it fixed?

Comment: @jrojasqu The macro `\spaceouthelpA` parses word by word, while `\spaceouthelpB` parses each word character by character.  Yes, I could add a separate inter-word space, and I will edit my MWE to implement that.

Comment: @jrojasqu Please see revision.

Comment: I did, it is great! Hopefully I can find an optimal word spacing with your macro. Using proportional spacing gives a more refined aspect.

Comment: @jrojasqu  I have made an addditional edit, when I realized that `\theWordSpace` should be based on `\LocalLetterSpace` and not `\theLetterSpace`.  Please use this later version.

Comment: This is awesome :) Now I can replace `soul` for spacing

Comment: @jrojasqu  I don't know how `soul` handles it, but one must be careful if macros are included in the argument to `\spaceout`.  As you saw, I surrounded my `\textcolor` invocation with an additional set of braces.  I make no guarantees when it comes to other macros.