# Reducing letter spacing to get rid of a widow, how much is appropriate?

Tags: microtype, widows-orphans

Some times the only way to get rid of a widow is, to reduce the letter spacing in a certain paragraph or footnote. Being addicted to XeLateX unfortunately I can't use the `microtype` package to achieve that aim, so I'm helping my self with this command:

```
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-0.1} Some text I have to shrunk unfortunately
to kill a fat, old, dirty, greedy, avaricious, mean (but rich?) old 
widow.\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=0}
```

But my question is: How fare can I go without risking to change the grey scale of my page? What is reasonable here?

Comment: What about answers of [How do I prevent widow/orphan lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-do-i-prevent-widow-orphan-lines)?

Comment: @Fran I know the answers but some times you get widows anyway.

Comment: I recommend developing an addiction to `luatex`.  You won’t face this problem as often, because you can use many features of `microtype` with `luatex`, and if you do find yourself wanting or perhaps needing to play with the letter-spacing, you can load `chickenize` and use its `\colorstretch` macro to check the greyness.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166598/cutting-corners-how-to-delete-1-pt-0-3515-mm-or-so

Comment: Actually, my answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231679/one-single-colored-letter-inside-spacedallcaps/231702#231702, when used with a negative argument, will also provide a remedy.  Using that code, compare `one single col{\textcolor{red}{o}}red letter` to `\def\theWordSpace{0pt}
\spaceout[-.3pt]{one single col{\textcolor{red}{o}}red letter}`.

Comment: Based on thinking about your question, I have modified my answer here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230840/artificially-improving-default-tex-algo-results-for-balancing-interword-spacing/230855#230855, to use both inter-letter and inter-word spacing changes (see ADDENDUM to the answer) to achieve either a stretching or shrinking of the text.